# Understanding django

Tags: python, django

New at this and trying to learn python and django. I'll cut right to the chase. I'm reading the django tutorial on the main site and I see that you can set up a database in django with class variables like those given here

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Later in the tutorial, a Poll object is created using

```
p = Poll(question="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
```

My question is: it appears as though strings are being passed using named arguments, yet in the class, these appear to be objects constructed using `models`. So how does django convert the string, "What's new?", to become a question object?

Comment: That's the hidden magic ;) `models.Model` has a constructor that accepts keyword args (`**kwargs`) and gets anything you pass it. You can even pass unexisting arguments to it, and Django will notify you that they are unneeded.

Comment: Therein may lie the problem: the details are so well hidden that it is difficult for me to understand how it is all happening.

Comment: @MattCremeens dont go deep if you are new in django. otherwise you get confused. just watch how they work and enjoy it. later things come automatically to your mind ..

Comment: I am starting to get the hang of it after reading all of these answers and comments. I am grateful for the help of this community and wish I could give everyone credit for the answer.

Comment: @MattCremeens right. My advice: *DON'T START LEARNING PYTHON WITH DJANGO*. I used to dislike Django because it did some things without me knowing about it, and it was driving me nuts. However, that's the philosophy of Django - to make everything as simple as possible, thought very unobvious sometimes. If you're new to Python, I'd suggest you to try something more lightweight and explicit - Flask, for example.

Comment: @MattCremeens django community is the best community ever in software world. so awesome people hang out there who help you with big heart. i was like you back in the days, these wonderful people kept me motivated in every question i asked.. keep it up

Comment: This has been awesome and so far you are proven correct, @doniyor. I have learned a number of other languages, but somehow python/django seem quite different from what I'm used to. I will push on like you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewDunai, I believe that to be good advice, but unfortunately I don't have a choice. I've been handed a django project to work on and so I need to quickly get up to speed in both python and django. I am trying my best, but it does feel like a struggle.

Comment: @MattCremeens I understand. Anyway, I still encourage you to learn basic Python tricks before proceeding with Django things. You can do both, but put Python at higher priority. Read about Python OOP - classes, inheritance, decorators etc. ;) Good luck!

Comment: @MattCremeens Trust me it's worth it. I didn't know anything about Django two years ago and couldn't even imagine coding in any framework other than ASP.NET and c#. Just like you I was thrown into the Django world by an employer. Now I enjoy every minute of coding in Django and my performance is tripled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define your model class you are just defining your model schema for Django. Django uses this information to create a table and hold your objects. So, when you say:

```
question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

a text field is created in database and Poll objects will have a question field that hold a string.

Comment: So when an object is constructed, it receives text that django somehow knows to push it to the database?

Comment: Yes exactly. All of the magic happens when you inherit models.Model.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is that `question` and `pub_date` are not typical object properties: they are *class properties*. Django uses them to understand what you want the model to look like.

Later, when you create a `Poll` class that extends `models.Model`, Django takes a look at `question` and `pub_date` class properties and creates an object that stores them as **object properties**.

For example, let's try to create our own ORM:

```
class CoolModel:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.values = {}
        for field, value in kwargs.items():
            if getattr(self, field, None):
                self.values[field] = value
            else:
                raise Exception('Unknown model field - {}!'.format(field))

class CoolField(object):
    pass

# Here we create our model:

class Poll(CoolModel):
    name = CoolField()
    date = CoolField()

m1 = Poll(name='test', date='yesterday?')
print m1.values  # Prints '{"name": "test", "date": "yesterday"}'
m2 = Poll(name='test2', some_field="wtf") # Raises Exception:
                                               # Unknown model field = some_field!
```

That's how Django does it.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't convert it to anything since from the provided `Poll` class, `question` is defined as a `CharField` (text) and not as an object. Django won't do any magic !

Comment: OK, so it receives text, not an object, that gets stored in `question`. Somehow, though, the `question` gets stored in my mysql database, correct? But how?

Comment: @MattCremeens ``question`` is just a column of ``Poll`` Table. new question text will just go into new table row as a new data table

Comment: @MattCremeens Try to find the Apress book called Pro Django.  I think it will help you understand what is under the hood with Django

Comment: @joelgoldstick, that may be my next book after a more basic one. You all have certainly been inspiring. So glad I asked the question. :)

Comment: My 2 cents: The Pro Django is really advanced - try to have lots of experience with django before starting it or you'll definitely get lost :|